# Android Custom Preference changing Override

Tags: android, preference

My custom preference class helps color picking.
The custom-preference calls GridView Intent it's include 9 colors.
But My custom class can't refresh color which user-selected on gridview
When I finish the preference intent, then re-launch preference,
The Color showing up me as I selected.

`onBindView()` Method, I overried. It's perfect.
**But I don't know what method I must override to refresh color.**

[image]

```
public class ConfigImage extends Preference
{
    Context mContext;

    public ConfigImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public ConfigImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.mContext = context;
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_image);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindView(View view)
    {
        super.onBindView(view);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.preference_image_iv_color);
        if (imageView != null)
        {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            int colorIndex = sharedPref.getInt("setting_color_default", 3);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ColorStorage.colors[colorIndex]));
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
    <PreferenceCategory
    android:key="setting_color_info"
    android:title="색상" >

    <com.pack.ConfigImage
        android:id="@+id/setting_color_default"
        android:key="setting_color_default"
        android:selectable="true"
        android:summary="Choose default color"
        android:title="Default Color"
        settings:background="#FFFFFFFF" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your problem is not getting notified of the change in shared preference then you should subscribe to it's change like

```
registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```